# using Events and Streams without RxJS

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm not sure why one should use RxJS(ReactiveX).

There is already a good EventEmitter <-> Listener in Javascript eco.

You can `emit()` and `addEventListener()` for that Subject(Observable) which seems same as using RxJS.

Also there are many "stream" APIs that can be used instead of RxJS.

For example there is `fs.createReadStream()` method that has `'data'` event.

So when dealing with file inputs you don't need RxJS.

Can anyone tell me in which scenario RxJS is better or different over EventEmitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJs has a massive amount of utility functions that combine stream, filter streams, manipulate data in the streams, cache, replay, throttle and lots more. If you are programming reactively it gives you a massive amount of power to create an observable of the data you need.